# recording flv broken red5

Tags: java, server, red5, red5-recorder

I am using red5 server 1.0.6

Some of my recorded files are broken, I have read in some articles that if a stream is closed before the `bufferLength` of the stream is greater than `0`, the recorded file will be broken. This is my code for saving and closing the stream.

```
@Override public void streamPublishStart(IBroadcastStream stream) {
    try {
        /* My script to save started stream details in database */
        stream.saveAs("audio/"+username, true);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}

@Override public void streamBroadcastClose(IBroadcastStream stream) {
    /* My script to save closed stream details in database */
    stream.close();
}
```

Is the `stream.close()` reason for broken recordings? What happens if I don't close the stream?

Comment: Hi! What do you mean with broken? Can you open the file but the quality is bad?

Comment: It's not playing at all

Comment: If I execute ffmpeg command it is giving invalid data found while processing input

Comment: flvmeta author here. `flvmeta --check` can be used to diagnose such problems. It might tell you exactly how the file is broken.

Comment: Do you need to use the isAppend flag in true? Did you get the same result doing stream.saveAs("audio/"+username, false)?

Comment: No, I haven't tried that.

Comment: I want to save all the data in same file

Comment: During your transmission, do you have any suscriber listening the audio? Only to check if the problem is maybe on the client. Do you have this problem always?

Comment: Do you have some .ser files with the same name on your streams folder when this happens?

Comment: Yes I have 2 subscribers listening to that stream.

Comment: Nope, no .ser or .info files in my folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100505/discussion-between-vishnu-and-andres).

Comment: @SirDarius I will try that tomorrow and ping you

Comment: @SirDarius it is show `0x00000000: fatal F11002: FLV signature not found in header
1 error(s), 0 warning(s)`

Comment: Well, the file is not a valid FLV file then. That's pretty much all I can say, unfortunately.

Comment: It played well in live stream. file metadata is shown if I use flvreader(Java). is it possible to add FLV signature to the file?